# Extjs tagfield saving values in inputbox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, tags

This is the first time I am working on ExtJs. I am trying to create a tagfield with all selection stored in the inputfield as values.

Right now I think all the values are saved as the `<li></li>` tags.

Is there a way I could save selection as csv in the value attribute to the field ?
I want to change the template to parse CSV values and select the items in the dropdown.

Comment: what does your code look like now?

Comment: I have just extended "Ext.form.field.Tag" . 

Basically, I am trying to get a multiselect combobox with values displayed as CSV.

Since multiselect combobox has been deceprecated in version 6.2 I had to use tagfield. my problem is that I want to have field value as CSV and not as an array.

Comment: can you pls put your code here [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)?

Comment: It's nothing more than a blank class extending the "'Ext.form.field.Tag". All i want to know is is there a way to use the tagfield to have all the CSV values saved in the input box and then load it up while rendering? @Njdhv

Comment: I found something what I want to accomplish. http://jsfiddle.net/dFEsc/16/ but with tagfield on 6.2 @Njdhv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a different data format during form submission, you have to override the [`getSubmitData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#method-getSubmitData) function of the tagfield.

I have made an example for you - not with CSV, but with the array encoded as JSON:

[Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27vo)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alexander. This is really helpful. I checked the DOM, Is there a way I can set the value attribute of the drop down element with the value we are getting in the <span> tag right now.

"Text 2, Text 1"

<span id="mytagfield-1010-selectedText" data-ref="selectedText" aria-hidden="true" class="x-hidden-clip">Selected Text 2, Text 1.</span>

I apologise for my lack of knowledge on the subject.